# SQL Grouping even and odd

Tags: sql, oracle

I have  to Group Certain data as so that it comes in 2 sets.

Attached image has details of actal data, expected result and data from  query I used.

I am sure i am missing something in group by of max option .Please help [image]

```
  select agrmnt_id ,location_name, slab_no,target_start,target_end, tier_perc ,mod(RANK, 2) col from 
        (select agrmnt_id ,location_name, slab_no, target as target_start ,LAG(target) OVER (PARTITION BY location_name ORDER BY slab_no DESC)-1 as target_end  ,PAY_PREC|| '%' as tier_perc,
          DENSE_RANK() over(partition by agrmnt_id order by location_name) RANK
        from plb_addnl_slab_details 
        where agrmnt_id='PLBCAI140262' order by location_name,slab_no
        )) group by agrmnt_id,location_name ,slab_no
        order by location_name1 ,slab_no1,  location_name2 ,slab_no2
```

Comment: An image of your schema and data is not very helpful. Text is much more friendly. Even better is to set up a [demo on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/45f1b/1), although your query as it is now gets an ORA-00933.

Comment: Actually, that's SQL Fiddle being fussy; but where is [`PAY_PERC` coming from](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/45f1b/5)? And the columns/aliases in your `order by`? What are your criteria for linking these, `slab_no`? And how do you choose the order of the link? Where does odd/even come into it? Please explain your logic clearly...

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you want, which is more than a little doubtful, it seems like you are able to generate a list of all the values you want, but you can't get them aligned in two sets? If so I think you need to treat your initial list as a base view and left outer join it to itself, using your `col` value to decide which is in first set and which in the second.

The criteria for joining seem a bit vague. If I add another ranking to stop the same values appearing twice in the second columns, I can get your expected result with this:

```
with t as (
  select agrmnt_id, location_name, slab_no, target_start, target_end,
    tier_perc , mod(col_rnk, 2) col, rnk
  from (
    select agrmnt_id, location_name, slab_no, target as target_start,
      LAG(target) OVER (PARTITION BY location_name
        ORDER BY slab_no DESC)-1 as target_end,
      SLAB_PERC|| '%' as tier_perc,
      DENSE_RANK() over(partition by agrmnt_id order by location_name) col_rnk,
      RANK() over(partition by agrmnt_id, slab_no order by location_name) rnk
    from plb_addnl_slab_details
    where agrmnt_id='PLBCAI140262'
  )
)
select t1.agrmnt_id as agrmnt_id_1, t1.location_name as location_name_1,
  t1.slab_no as slab_no_1, t1.target_start as target_start_1,
  t1.target_end as target_end_1,
  t2.agrmnt_id as agrmnt_id_2, t2.location_name as location_name_2,
  t2.slab_no as slab_no_2, t2.target_start as target_start_2,
  t2.target_end as target_end_2
from t t1
left join t t2 on t2.agrmnt_id = t1.agrmnt_id
and t2.slab_no = t1.slab_no
and t2.rnk = t1.rnk + 1
and t2.col = 0
where t1.col = 1
order by t1.agrmnt_id, t1.location_name, t1.slab_no;
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/45f1b/20). I'm not convinced those join conditions (or the new rank) are quite right but can't really tell without more data, or more information about the logic you want to use. Hopefully this gives you something you can adapt though.